# Synchronizing perl packages from one install to another

Tags: linux, installation, perl

I currently have perl 5.8.8 installed on a production linux system, and there are many, many packages installed.  I am planning on installing perl 5.16 under a prefix (from source).  Is there any way for me to tell cpan that I want to install into this new location the latest version of all packages that currently exist in the existing installation?

I can write a script to walk my current PERL5LIB to build a list of things to install, but I am hoping there is some way pre-built way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the [autobundle](https://metacpan.org/module/perlfaq3#How-do-I-find-which-modules-are-installed-on-my-system-) feature, which creates an installable 'Bundle' of all the Perl modules on your system.

I recommend against installing the newest versions of all the modules. Instead, I recommend installing the *same* versions. There are is no guarantee that the newer versions are compatible with your application. Unless you have a comprehensive test suite, you are increasing the risk of your upgrade by expanding the scope of work that needs to be tested.

I recently upgraded an app with more than 100,000 lines of code from 5.8 to 5.14, and it went surprisingly smoothly. We stuck with the same versions where we could and found there was high compatibility.

Comment: this appears to be what I was looking for, thanks.